# Import mongodb dump consistent with Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, dump

I have a new Django App. I import json dump into mongodb using terminal like:

```
mongoimport --db mydb --collection mycollection --file myfile.json
```

The files are well displayed within the admin panel. But when I create a new entry into the mycollection via admin panel, Django gives it an id which is already in the mongo json dump.

Is there a way to tell Django to be consistent with the database and start incrementing the id from the last entry in the database collection?

Comment: If you got the solution, can you please share it here

Comment: @brijexecon I wrote a python script to insert all the values from the json to the new db. I couldn't find any solution though.

Comment: Thanks @vidor-vistrom I appreciate If you can share the script.

Comment: @brijexecon The script is specific to my use case. All you have to do is read the json inside django, extract your data and hit the db inside a django function inside views.py